# concatenate strings together in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

how to i concatenate strings in objective c?

```
- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender {
MFMailComposeViewController *mailContoller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
[mailContoller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
NSString *email = @"*******gmail.com";
NSString *email1 = @"*******@hotmail.co.uk";
NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:email, email1, nil];
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@",
textField1.text, textField2.text, textField3.text];
[mailContoller setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
[mailContoller setToRecipients:emailArray];
[mailContoller setSubject:@"IT WORKS!"];
[self presentViewController:mailContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[[self myTextView] resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Yeah. Deleted it, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest case:

```
NSString* concatenatedString = [stringA stringByAppendingString: stringB];
```

From your code, this:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@", textField1.text, textField2.text, textField3.text];
```

might be better expressed as:

```
NSString *message = [@[textField1.text, textField2.text, textField3.text] componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];
```

`+stringWithFormat:` is comparatively expensive when there's nothing but simple concatenation going on.

Comment: i just keep getting a message saying undeclared variable when i input this code.

Comment: Naturally, you need to replace `stringA` and `stringB` with your string variables.